# First order differential equation $(2t-x)+(4x-t)x'=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I would like to ask you for a help with solving $(2t-x)+(4x-t)x'=0.$
I am able to solve for example $x’=x+t$ or $x’=x/t+t/x$ (by replacement $y=x/t$). But I don't know what to do in this case. Please kindly guide me.
I tried:

1. $dx/dt=(-2t+x)/(4x-t)$ but I don't know how to get $f(x)dx=g(t)dt.$
2. I tried to replace $x/t=y$ but then I get $y’t+y=(y-2)/(4t-1)$ and still dont know how to simplify it.

Comment: Try editing with latex and attempt to reopen

Comment: The last equation in 2 should be $y't+y=(y-2)/(4y-1)$. This equation is separable:  $$y't=-y+\frac{y-2}{4y-1} \implies \frac{dy}{-y+\frac{y-2}{4y-1}}=\frac{dt}{t}.$$

Comment: Try it this way - get rid of the denominators *including* the differential denominators.  Then, group together the terms where you have the same variable/differential together, and then take the ones where they are different, and see if you can make the "different" ones into a form that is a differential of a product or quotient.